# What is the best way to resize a Bitmap in Windows?

Tags: winapi, bitmap, gdi

So, I am working on a text editor. I use double buffering to paint on to the screen. So basically I have an offscreen bitmap, which I paint on, and then copy it to the screen. Now, when the window for the text editor resizes, I need to resize the offscreen bitmap as well. So what would be a good way to resize the bitmap? I was thinking to maybe delete the old object and create a new bitmap using `CreateCompatibleBitmap`, but I'm wondering if it's the correct way to do it.

Language : C++ using Win32 API

Comment: Language? I take it C++ or C, but...

Comment: Why exactly do you need to resize it? That sounds like it's going to take time and I can't see the benefit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Presumably the bitmap used for the back buffer is sized to be the same as the window.  If the window grows, then the code will need a larger back buffer. The back buffer could be made as large as the virtual desktop, but that might be absurdly large. Also, blitting a portion of a huge bitmap can be inefficient, and the desktop size can change, so you'd still have to deal with resizing.  Tiled approaches can suffer from tearing and flicker, which misses the point of using a back buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CreateCompatibleBitmap will work, and then you'll want to call [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on it to copy the contents of your existing backbuffer to the resized buffer. I don't think there is a more efficient way to do it using GDI.

Answer (score 2):

If are thinking about using CreateCompatibleBitmap with BitBlt, you might like to look at StretchBlt instead.  StretchBlt works like BitBlt but resizes the source image to fit into the destination area.