# change HBITMAP resolution for reducing file size

Tags: c, winapi, sockets, bitmap, resolution

i create screenshot of desktop as bitmap file.

What is best method to reduce the resolution of this large image file (~3 MB) in win32 C?

I want to send it over the network, so the file should be smaller.

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191642/what-is-the-best-way-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-windows

Comment: instead of reducing the image resolution, consider saving it as jpeg. The file size should come down dramatically.

Answer (score 3):

use [StretchBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to resize the bitmap or use gdi+ api to convert bitmap to jpeg. please take a look at http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/327090/how-to-convert-screenshotbmp-to-jpeg#.