# How to shrink a bitmap to fit in a static control?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I have a bitmap that I want to put into a static control. I have the static control as a `SS_BITMAP` style and when I use the `_staticControl.SetBitmap(myBitmap.Detach())` method the static control gets resized to the area of the bitmap which is bigger than that control. I know that the `SS_BITMAP` style resizes the control automatically, but how do I shrink the bitmap to fit in the static control? I've tried using a `SS_REALSIZECONTROL` style, but this doesn't show the bitmap at all. Is there any of these other styles I should be applying? [Static Control Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The title asks something very different from the body of the question. It seems you already know how to display a bitmap in a static control, and that your *actual* question is how to shrink the bitmap to fit in the static control. Static controls do *not* automatically scale bitmaps (there are no styles for this), so if you want that, you need to do it yourself. `StretchBlt` will do what you need; subclass the static control and handle its `WM_PAINT` messages.

Comment: Is there anyway to resize the bitmap and still use `SetBitmap()` without subclassing the control? The bitmap is a screenshot taken just before I want to display it on the control.

Comment: Yes, but it still involves `StretchBlt`. You just draw it onto a new bitmap selected into a temporary (memory) DC, and then save that as your resized bitmap, deleting the original. Like it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191642/what-is-the-best-way-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-windows), but you'll use `StretchBlt` to shrink it, instead of `BitBlt` (which would draw it at a 1:1 size).

Comment: Aslo SS_OWNERDRAW may be a more straightforward way to go, you still do StretchBlt yourself, but no subclassing